# Display String based on Int Value in a SELECT JOIN statement

Tags: sql

I have a select statement which I want to convert to string depending on it's value i.e.

I want something along the lines of:

```
SELECT SchoolID (IF SchoolID = 1 Convert STRING("London"), IF SchoolID = 2 Convert STRING ("Glasglow") ELSE Convert STRING(new school")), 
L.Location
FROM Schools SC
Join Location L
On L.LocationID = SC.LocationID 
Where SchoolID < 200
```

Not sure how to approach this.

Many Thanks,
Sam

-- EDIT The parenthesis is the Syntax I should be looking at not the actual code

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Looks like some non-ANSI SQL there.)

Comment: Why the case expression? Don't you have the SchoolID's and their cities stored in a table?

Comment: Looks like the case for CASE, but you'd better show sample data and desired result to be sure.

Comment: @jarlh - Nope it was never implement

Comment: So, that's the main problem. Until that is fixed, take a look at the answers you've already got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` expression like this:

```
SELECT SchoolID
, case SchoolID
    when 1 then 'London'
    when 2 then 'Glasglow'
    else        'new school' 
  end as SchoolName
, L.Location
FROM Schools SC
Join Location L
On L.LocationID = SC.LocationID 
Where SchoolID < 200
```

Comment: Thanks Kobi, I knew it was something simple!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SchoolID, CASE SchoolID 
WHEN 1 THEN 'London' 
WHEN 2 THEN 'Glasglow'
ELSE 'new school'
END AS New_Value , 
L.Location
FROM Schools SC
Join Location L
On L.LocationID = SC.LocationID 
Where SchoolID < 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Case statements can also be written like this:

```
SELECT SchoolID, 
       CASE WHEN SchoolID = 1 THEN 'London'
       WHEN SchoolID = 2 THEN 'Glasglow'
       ELSE 'new school'
       END AS city , 
       L.Location
FROM Schools SC
JOIN LOCATIONL ON L.LocationID = SC.LocationID 
WHERE SchoolID < 200
```

Comment: At least slightly better indentation.

Comment: @Suraz If you read my comment, you can see that I state "Case statements can also be written like this:" emphasis on "also". E.g. 'CASE WHEN SchoolID = 1 THEN 'London'' instead of  'CASE SchoolID 
WHEN 1 THEN 'London''. Thanks for being supporting for a new comer.

Comment: @Suraz I disagree with that the fact, that you say it's not a matter of anyone's support. My understanding is that this site is set up to help people e.g. questions asked, questions answered or alternative answers given. It might be a simple question for you, but not for the user who asked, hence they needed help. Don't think everyone is on the same level as you. If you have a problem or disagree with something, advice the other person, don't have a go at them. Also, you contradict yourself, by initially saying my answer is a "duplicate answer" and then now saying it's a "similar answer...".

Comment: @Vijey You are right sorry for my words but remember one thing I have also started from the beginning and faced so many comments, feedback and argument ... in the site so we have to learn from the feedback whatever we got neither disputing on that. Your answer is 100% right in all the terms so  +1 for that. I am just trying to build up my profile ...I always try to give distinct answer whatever the complexity of the question. I know every question is difficult so it is asked here.

Comment: @Suraz Thank you for understanding my point of view. I just wanted to make you aware, that a lot of us are still learning to become experienced guys like yourself. Also, very generous of you to give me a +1, thanks :)